Parse error near `\n' in .zshrc file after updating Amazon Q
After updating Amazon Q on my Macbook, I get an error every time I open a terminal, which looks like this:
/Users/dylan/.zshrc:24: parse error near `\n'
dylan@Dylans-MBP-2 ~ % 

When I navigate to my .zshrc file, it looks like this:
# Amazon Q post block. Keep at the bottom of this file.
[[ -f "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/amazon-q/shell/zshrc.post.zsh" ]] && builtin source "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/amazon-q/shell/zshrc.post.zsh"


The 24th line of the file is technically the newline that follows the last written line.
I tried looking for characters that it might not be able to understand. I also tried to delete the newline which then gave me the following error:
/Users/dylanravel/.zshrc:23: parse error near `"${HOME}/Library/App...'

Let me know if you guys know a fix to these errors! Thank you in advance!

That error could indicate an issue anywhere in the file, e.g. from an open paren that doesn't have a matching close paren.  Try starting a new shell with debugging turned on: zsh -x. That'll produce a lot of output that you may be able to use to find the problematic statement. exit will take you back to the prior shell that doesn't have debugging turned on.

Comment out lines in your .zshrc one by one from the bottom, until the error disappears. It could be that you have a run-away string, i.e. a starting quote without corresponding ending quote.

Thank you @Gairfowl and @user1934428. You both pointed me in the correct direction!
After you pointed out that the error could be anywhere in the file, I took your advice and went line by line, commenting out lines until the error disappeared.
It ended up being an issue with this line:
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fieval "$(zoxide init zsh)"

I successfully fixed this line by changing it to:
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; eval "$(zoxide init zsh)"; fi

Thank you all for your help! Have a wonderful day!

this is why you shall format a code

The zoxide eval should probably go on its own line, not within the rbenv if statement
